# What causes this error "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out" in AWS Cloud9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-vpc, cloud9, vpc

I am trying to push my commits to github in AWS Cloud9, which I was previously able to do. However, I attempted to follow the instructions here
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html?icmpid=docs_ac9_ide#app-preview-share 
to make the application public, and since doing so, I see the above error when I try to push my commits. Which setting is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think what likely happened is that when you updated the default Network ACL associated with your instance's subnet, you changed the default settings, which I believe allow all inbound and outbound traffic. If you update your settings with Type: ALL Traffic and set to allow, it should work again.